# CSS hover transition not chaning color of an icon on unhover on Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I'm chaning background color and text color on hover in menu - simply case. In all browsers everything works well, but in **Firefox** (normal and developer edition (version 58.0b1)) when I'm hovering the navbar element few times the icon after unhover does not change the color back and it looks like this: 
[image: icon]
and it should look like this:

[image: proper icon].

---

HTML element:

```
<a href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Plan dnia
</a>
```

CSS before:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #314461;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

CSS after:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    background-color: #4D87EA;
    color: white;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```

I would like to emphasise that when I remove the transition from the above css, everything works well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your apply also in i element like so:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover > i,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus > i {
    background-color: #4D87EA;
    color: white;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunetaly, it's not the solution.